# jest multiple attributes to be defined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Is there a way to check for multiple attributes toBeDefined in jest tests.

Right now am doing,

```
expect(a.startTime).toBeDefined();
expect(a.userId).toBeDefined();
expect(a.loaded).toBeDefined();
expect(a.session).toBeDefined();
expect(a.version).toBeDefined();
```

Can these be combined into a singe-line expect ?

I wrote the test as `expect(a.startTime && a.userId && a.loaded)....toBeDefined();`

But the reviewers rejected it saying the && might not test the existence in the right way and precisely not say which of the attribute is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend defining the shape of `a` (the below is an assumption, so you'll need to adjust it to your needs):

```js
expect(a).toEqual(
  expect.objectContaining({
    startTime: expect.any(Date),
    userId: expect.any(String),
    loaded: expect.any(Boolean),
    session: expect.objectContaining({ ... }),
    version: expect.any(Number)
  })
);
```

[expect.any](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectanyconstructor)

[expect.objectContaining](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectobjectcontainingobject) (using this allows you to match against SOME of the properties while ignoring others; however, if you want match against an object and ALL of its properties, then just use: `{ }`)

The above is a general way to match against the properties by asserting against their data type. You could also use real: strings, objects, booleans, numbers, etc to match against as well. Avoid using `toBeDefined()` as it's not very specific to what is defined (a number? a boolean? a string? a function?).

Comment: just to highlight(up to my experience it's terra incognita for many React developers): we can use `expect.any` or even `expect.anything` not only in `objectContaining()` but in other jest's assertions as well(say, in `.arrayContaining()` or even `.toEqual()`)